# Advanced Custom Field checkbox query not working

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, advanced-custom-fields

I am using an Advanced Custom Field to allocate a custom field to posts.
This field is then used by a filtering system to filter posts using a custom query (via the *pre_get_posts* action). The other query arguments are working fine, except for the one which relies on ACF’s field.

The current query arguments of the field’s *meta_query* have been constructed according to the [ACF documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/checkbox/#template-usage) for the field (hence the quotation marks surrounding the value).

Can anyone advise me as to where this is going wrong? The query doesn’t seem to return any posts based on the values I am passing to the query.

Query arguments:

```
$courses = get_query_var('courses');
if ($courses) {
    $query->set('meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key' => 'course_check',
                'value' => '"'.$courses.'"', //i.e mdia-403
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of this issue by print_r’ing the entire query and inspecting what was actually going on - had done this a number of times, but overlooked the following detail:

The issue here wasn’t actually due to the checkbox meta_query, but a conflict between the get_query_var term (‘courses’) and a custom taxonomy whose slug is also ‘courses’.

When the query was executed, the query seemed to be querying for posts associated with both the custom taxonomy and the selected checkbox value, yielding no results.

Renaming the  name attr to something other than courses then reconfiguring the registered query var and  meta_query fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

ACF stores checkbox values in array, that's the reason your code is not working.

See working example here:
https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/wp_query-using-meta_query-for-an-acf-checkbox-field/

Comment: thanks for your response. Yeah, I read in the documentation that the values are stored in a serialised array; hence my use of quote marks for the value and the LIKE comparison.

Not sure what I’m missing compared to the example you have shown me. Their use of the foreach is presumably due to having multiple selections activated on the checkbox field, where mine is single-selection and the values are derived from the URL.

Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If it's a single selection checkbox, value is still an array in database. So this is not working?
`array(
                'key' => 'course_check',
                'value' => $courses, //i.e mdia-403
                'compare' => 'IN'
            ),`

Comment: No it doesn’t, although your suggestion conflicts with the ACF docs - you need to encapsulate the value in quotes i.e. '"'.$courses.’”’. I have also tried both the LIKE and IN comparisons.